# Compare 2 different csv files and output all the changes into a new csv

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

I have 2 CSVs which are New.csv and Old.csv shown below:

Old.csv

```
longName,shortName,eventType,number,severity
ACTAGENT201,ACAT201,RES,1,INFO
ACTAGENT202,ACAT202,RES,2,ALERT
ACODE801,AC801,ADMIN,1,MINOR
ACODE802,AC802,ADMIN,2,MINOR
ACODE102,AC102,COMM,2,CRITICAL
ACODE103,AC103,COMM,3,CRITICAL
ACODE104,AC104,COMM,4,CRITICAL
ACODE105,AC105,COMM,5,CRITICAL
ACODE106,AC106,COMM,6,CRITICAL
```

New.csv

```
longName,shortName,eventType,number,severity
ACTAGENT201,ACAT201,RES,1,INFO
ACTAGENT202,ACAT202,RES,2,ALERT
ACODE801,AC801,ADMIN,1,MINOR
ACODE802,AC802,ThisHasBeenChanged,2,MINOR
ACODE102,AC102,COMM,2,CRITICAL
ACODE103,AC103,COMM,3,CRITICAL
ACODE104,AC104,COMM,4,THISHASBEENCHANGED
ACODE105,AC105,COMM,5,CRITICAL
ACODE106,AC106,COMM,6,CRITICAL
```

If there is data in one of the columns in the row that has been modified/changed between the old.csv and the new.csv then that whole row should be appended to the changes.csv like this with each column from old.csv and new.csv beside each other:

[image]

I know how to find new and deleted items in the csv, but could not figure out how to get the modified items. Code below:

```
import csv

def DeletedItems(old_csv, new_csv, changes_csv):
    with open(new_csv, newline="", encoding="utf8") as new_fp:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(new_fp)
        csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
        new_long_names = {row[0] for row in csv.reader(new_fp)}
    with open(old_csv, newline="", encoding="utf8") as old_fp:
        with open(changes_csv, "a", newline="", encoding="utf8") as changes_fp:
            writer = csv.writer(changes_fp)
            writer.writerow("")
            for row in csv.reader(old_fp):
                if row[0] not in new_long_names:
                    writer.writerow(row)

def NewItems(old_csv, new_csv, changes_csv):
    with open(old_csv, newline="", encoding="utf8") as old_fp:
        csv_reader = csv.reader(old_fp)
        csv_headings = next(csv_reader)
        old_long_names = {row[0] for row in csv.reader(old_fp)}
    with open(new_csv, newline="", encoding="utf8") as new_fp:

        with open(changes_csv, "w", newline="", encoding="utf8") as changes_fp:
            writer = csv.writer(changes_fp)
            for row in csv.reader(new_fp):
                if row[0] not in old_long_names:
                    writer.writerow(row)

NewItems("old.csv", "new.csv", "changes.csv")
DeletedItems("old.csv", "new.csv", "changes.csv")
```

Comment: Modified = key/id/whatever identifies the entry is the same, while line is not the same. So something like `line_old['longName'] == line_new['longName'] and line_old != line_new`

Comment: Are the `longName`s unique?

Comment: Yes the longnames and shortnames are unique @PranavHosangadi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, read both CSV files into a *dictionary*, using the `longName` values as keys.

```
import csv

with open(old_csv_file, "r") as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    old_csv = {row[0]: row for row in reader}

with open(new_csv_file, "r") as fh:
    reader = csv.reader(fh)
    new_csv = {row[0]: row for row in reader}
```

Then, it's easy to find newly added and deleted keys using set operations.

```
old_longNames = set(old_csv.keys())
new_longNames = set(new_csv.keys())

# common: set intersection
common_longNames = old_longNames.intersection(new_longNames)
# removed: whatever's in old but not in new
removed_longNames = old_longNames - new_longNames
# added: whatever's in new but not in old
added_longNames = new_longNames - old_longNames
```

Finally, iterate over the common set to find where there are changes:

```
changed_longNames = []
for key in common_longNames:
    old_row = old_csv[key]
    new_row = new_csv[key]
    # if any(o != n for o, n in zip(old_row, new_row)):
    if old_row != new_row:
        # this row has at least one column changed. Do whatever
        print(f"LongName {key} has changes")
        changed_longNames.append(key)
```

Or, as a list comprehension:

```
changed_longNames = [key for key in common_longNames if old_csv[key] != new_csv[key]]
```

Writing everything to a new csv file is also fairly trivial. Note that the sets don't preserve the order, so you might not get the result in the same order.

```
with open("deleted.csv", "w") as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh)
    for key in removed_longNames:
        writer.writerow(old_csv[key])

with open("inserted.csv", "w") as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh)
    for key in added_longNames:
        writer.writerow(new_csv[key])

with open("changed.csv", "w") as fh:
    writer = csv.writer(fh)
    for key in changed_longNames:
        old_row = old_csv[key]
        new_row = new_csv[key]
        merged_row = []
        for oi, ni in zip(old_row, new_row):
            merged_row.append(oi)
            merged_row.append(ni)
        writer.writerow(merged_row)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for this. I am going to try to make it so that it puts everything into one csv file with the column names. I'll let u know if it works properly. Thanks again.

Comment: Hey @PranavHosangadi, I got it to output everything in one file with the column names. But, is there a way for "changes"  to have each column from the old csv and the new csv to be beside each other,  like my screenshot?

Comment: @joe_sanders Realized the link was for Python2, so I edited my answer.

Comment: You could also remove the multiple `with` and `writer = ...` since you want to write everything to one file. Just put all `for key in ...` loops in the same `with` block.

Comment: After your edit, the changed.csv is not outputting properly for me. I added a screenshot

Comment: @joe_sanders I accidentally appended the _entire row_ instead of the elements in the row. Do `merged_row.append(oi)` and `ni` instead of `old_row` and `new_row`. See latest edit

Comment: Hey @PranavHosangadi, for the changed.csv, I have been having trouble getting the column names to show up as "old" and "new" like in my screenshot. Is there a fairly simple way to do this?

Comment: `csv_headings` is the list you want to change. Do what we did to merge two lists -- `zip()`, and then append `" old"` or `" new"` to each element.